# Basis of eigenvectors common to H and B

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables, matrix-model

> Considering a three-dimensional state space spanned by the orthonormal basis formed by the three kets $|u_1\rangle,|u_2\rangle,|u_3\rangle $. In the basis of these three vectors, taken in order, are defined the operators
>   $$H=\hbar\omega_0 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & -1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & -1 \end{array} \right)  \qquad 
> B=b\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right) $$
>   with $\omega_0$ and $b$ real constants

My question is:

> How do I give a basis of eigenvectors common to H and B?

We know that $H$ and $B$ commute,that is $$[H,B]=0$$

Comment: One way is by finding eigenvectors of an arbitrary linear combination of $H$ and $B$, say $\alpha H + \beta B$.

Comment: $|u_1\rangle$ is a no brainer. For the others, try: $|u_2\rangle \pm |u_3\rangle$. Since, for $H$, $\lambda_2 =  \lambda_3$, any linear combination of their eigenvectors is also an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient to find the eigenstates of $B$ in the subspace spanned by $\vert 2\rangle=\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$ and $\vert 3\rangle=\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$.  The eigenstates of $B$ in that subspace will automatically also be eigenstates of $H$ because the similarity transformation $T$ that will diagonalize $B$ will be of the generic form
$$
T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0 \\
0&T_{22}&T_{23} \\
0&T_{32}&T_{33}\end{array}\right)
$$
and so will commute with $H$ on that subspace that $H$ on that subspace is (up to a scalar) the unit matrix.